# Data sets for Data warehouse research

Tags: database, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am working on a data warehouse project for my final year degree. My intention is to create a data warehouse within the Business Intelligence spectrum, that incorporates customers' information from a company's point-of-sales data for a given year or location for example. However, my problem is finding the right raw data for this purpose as I had been in contact with tens of companies who refused to share their own data!
Is there any source for a large free data set I can use to fit the above scenario i.e. Business Intelligence purpose? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe use Microsofts Northwind database. Also sometimes applications like Jaspersoft Server Community Edition etc. do have sample data with themselves. Getting data from a company will be very very hard since this data could hold corporate secrets and business advantages. You could easily be taken as someone who is trying to get confidential data, I guess.

Comment: You are right, but is there any way I can generate my own data according to my needs?

Comment: Sure. You have to create a data model, maybe already in Star Schema, maybe in 3nf, then create fake departments, fake transactions, fake customers, fake products and everything else a data warehouse usually holds. The question is if you have the time to create all this structure just for your case.

Comment: This is why I asked! I have a set up for a scenarios which in my case creating a data warehouse to a hotel. I designed the entity the assumed database Schema and also created the star schema as a result! My problem is finding the right data which fits to my scenario. I thought there were tools where can give a name of tables + the entities and would fill it up  with the required data

Comment: I don't think that there are tools for this specific use case which seems to happen not very often. If you know a thing or two about programming, you could take an easy language like python and fill the tables with random data. If you know the data model already, this might be the best way. Even if you got some data from businesses, they won't neccessessarily fit your Data Warehouse.